# Bootstrap floating labels can't click anywhere on input type text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Previously I used bootstrap v5.3.0 alpha1 and form-floating looks like this:
[image]

You see mouse is **correct** and I can click everywhere on input..
Now I installed new 5.3.0 alpha3 and it look like this:

[image]

This is zone where I can't click in each input where is floating label:

[image]

How to fix it?
Edit:
This is source code of login page where I can't click anywhere on input (bootstrap 5.3.0 alpha3):

```
<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }

    .form-signin {
        max-width: 330px;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    .form-signin .form-floating:focus-within {
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .form-signin input[type="text"] {
        margin-bottom: -1px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    }

    .form-signin input[type="password"] {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
</style>

<main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
    <form action="<?= MAINTENANCE_URL ?>" method="POST">
        <img src="<?= LOGO_ICON_COLOR_TRANSPARENT ?>" class="mb-4" style="height: 95px;">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>

        <div class="form-floating">
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="User"
                name="login">
            <label for="floatingInput">User</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password">
            <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
            <label>
                <?php
                if ($_GET['error']) {
                    echo "<span class='text-danger'>Chyba overenia</span>";
                }
                ?>
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
</main>
```

Source code where I can click anywhere on input (bootstrap 5.3.0 alpha1):

```
   <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            padding-top: 40px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }

        .form-signin {
            max-width: 330px;
            padding: 15px;
        }

        .form-signin .form-floating:focus-within {
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .form-signin input[type="text"] {
            margin-bottom: -1px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        }

        .form-signin input[type="password"] {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border-top-left-radius: 0;
            border-top-right-radius: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="text-center">

    <main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
        <form action="maintenance.php" method="POST">
            <img src="/assets/logo/icon/logoi_ct.png" class="mb-4" style="height: 95px;">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>

            <div class="form-floating">
                <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="User"
                    name="login">
                <label for="floatingInput">User</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password"
                    name="password">
                <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                <label>
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post the actual HTML and CSS that you have tried so we may best assist you here.

Comment: Now it working when I switched back to alpha1.

Comment: Always a chance things don't work properly in pre-released code branches  not yet ready for production use.  I have seen some that NEVER got to a release state (not specific to Bootstrap) for whatever reason it is/was.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code looks correctly, its a Bootstrap Error.
You should create an issue on the official GitHub Repo on Github:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues

But you don't need following code in css:

```
html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }
```

And if you like, you can fix it manually but for this, we need the Code from your Web Inspector and it can be more difficult to fix it. Bootstrap is a to large Framework to fix problems fast